Making a world map with Robinson projection
I am trying to make a world map with Robinson projection, but I am getting grey lines all over my map.
This is my code
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)
library(dplyr)

# Define Cruise Colors
Cruise.Colors <- c("I8S" = "#F70B0B", "I9N" = "#d1f08f", "P15S" = "#FFC40C", "P16N" = "#920000", "P16S" = "#F9DD8C", "AMT-19" = "#F37121", "AMT-20" = "#F4B18C", "GA02" = "#0CB5C6", "GA03" = "#5E0B5A", "GA10" = "#C84097", "GP13" = "#75653B", "MOSAiC" = "#008749", "Gradients_2" = "#7BC143", "Gradients_3" = "#004881", "IND_2017" = "#96D5E0", "KAXIS" = "#FFF0CB", "HEOBI" = "#EDB7DC", "POTATOE" = "#F29C4E", "FRAM_STRAIT" = "#a6a0a0")

# Load world map data
world <- shp <- ne_countries(type = "countries", 
                   scale = "medium",
                   returnclass = "sf")

# Prepare your data
worldmap.test.df <- grump_asv_long %>%
  distinct(SampleID, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  select(SampleID, Cruise_ID, Latitude, Longitude, Season) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Cruise_ID)) %>%
  filter(!Cruise_ID %in% c("MOSAiC"))

# Convert your data to an sf object
worldmap.test.df_sf <- st_as_sf(worldmap.test.df, coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude"), crs = 4326)

# Plotting
GRUMP.Map <- ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf(fill = "grey70", color = NA) + # Use light gray for land
  geom_sf(data = worldmap.test.df_sf, aes(color = Cruise_ID, shape = Season), size = 4, alpha = 0.8) +
  scale_color_manual(values = Cruise.Colors) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("Summer" = 16, "Autumn" = 17, "Winter" = 18, "Spring" = 19)) +
  coord_sf(crs = "+proj=robin +lon_0=180") +  # Robinson projection centered on the Pacific Ocean
  labs(title = "Southern Ocean",
       x = "Longitude",
       y = "Latitude") +
  theme_minimal() +
  ggtitle("GRUMP Map") +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 5))) # Adjust the legend size

GRUMP.Map

My data looks like this:
 SampleID  Cruise_ID  Season            geometry
 * <chr>    <chr>     <chr>          <POINT [°]>
 1 P-2      POTATOE   Summer      (-168.04 66.8)
 2 S0157    GA02      Summer  (-39.399 -47.8007)
 3 S0158    GA02      Summer  (-39.399 -47.8007)
 4 S0159    GA02      Summer  (-39.399 -47.8007)
 5 S0161    GA02      Summer  (-39.399 -47.8007)
 6 S0211    GA02      Summer (-48.7933 -48.9358)
 7 S0212    GA02      Summer (-48.7933 -48.9358)
 8 S0213    GA02      Summer (-48.7933 -48.9358)
 9 S0214    GA02      Summer   (-47.179 -46.907)
10 S0215    GA02      Summer   (-47.179 -46.907)

And my map looks like this:


This post answers your question. You need to use st_break_antimeridian(). In my answer on that post, just change +lon_0=-90 in the PROJ string to +lon_0=180, and st_break_antimeridian(lon_0 = -90) %>% to st_break_antimeridian(lon_0 = 180) %>%.
